# How to make Background Color fixed for dark mode and light mode of the device

Tags: android, uielement, android-darkmode

Hello i want to know that how can i set a fixed color to ui elements wheather the android device is in light mode or in dark mode

Here in my case there are some issues where the View in light mode of the device is set to my given color backgroud in light mode but when i switch the device to dark mode the View change its color to darkgrey which i didnt set

is there any way to fix this issues and also any tips on how can i do this in future with every ui element

Here is my Code

**BottomSheet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slidedownview"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_bottomsheetline"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**rounded_corner_bottomsheetline**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/lite_grey"
        android:startColor="@color/lite_grey" />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="25dp"
        android:topRightRadius="25dp" />

</shape>
```

color code

```
<color name="lite_grey">#e2e2e2</color>
```

**Output //Dark Mode**

as you can see the view is in dark grey color which i dint set ,the color i set is #e2e2e2

[image]

**Output // Normal or Light Mod**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the `themes.xml` folders and set the same colour everywhere for both day and night themes

Comment: can you give me some example if posible

Comment: open the themes.xml folder and check if all values are same for both day and night

Comment: actually there is one more issue , where the <view> background is not fixed and i dont know how can implement drawble layout in theme

Comment: what issue ? add it to the question

Comment: add `android:backgroundTint="@null"` to the view, it will solve the issue

Comment: share your `themes.xml` file

Comment: When you tell to check the theme i have checked and the bottomSheetDialogTheme was only in light theme and then i also aded it in dark ,and it worked fine but with the view i dont know how to do it so i just give it a background drawable

Comment: Please check the question i have updated it with output of dark mod